# Calculate new rectangle's corner (two geopoints) by doubling up diagonal

Tags: java, math, geometry, geo

I have rectangle defined by two geopoints:

```
1 -> 54.2749558,18.4287748 (lat, lng)
2 -> 54.4472187,18.9512795 (lat, lng)
```

And distance (diagonal) between those two points is 39km (calculated using [this](http://boulter.com/gps/distance/) algorithm). 
Now I need to double up my diagonal: 39km * 2 = 78km and find coordinates of new expanded rectangle (that has middle in the same place as the first rectangle).

Could someone help me out in creating that algorithm in Java?

EDIT:
My code using **Mbo's** answer:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //example data
    double lat1d = 54.2749558;
    double lng1d = 18.4287748;
    double lat2d = 54.4472187;
    double lng2d = 18.9512795;
    Coordinate lat1 = Coordinate.fromDegrees(lat1d);
    Coordinate lng1 = Coordinate.fromDegrees(lng1d);
    Point point1 = Point.at(lat1, lng1);

    Coordinate lat2 = Coordinate.fromDegrees(lat2d);
    Coordinate lng2 = Coordinate.fromDegrees(lng2d);
    Point point2 = Point.at(lat2, lng2);
    System.out.println("Point1: " + point1);
    System.out.println("Point2: " + point2);

    double distance = EarthCalc.gcdDistance(point1, point2); //in meters
    System.out.println("Current distance between points 1 and 2: " + distance);
    double newDistance = distance * 2;
    System.out.println("Needed distance between points 3 and 4: " + newDistance);


    double y = Math.sin(lng2d - lng1d) * Math.cos(lat2d);
    double x = Math.cos(lat1d) * Math.sin(lat2d) - Math.sin(lat1d) * Math.cos(lat2d) * Math.cos(lng2d - lng1d);
    double brng4 = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(y, x)); // bearing for calculating point 4

    double earthRadiusInMeters = EarthCalc.EARTH_DIAMETER / 2;
    double distanceByRadius4 = distance * 1.5 / (earthRadiusInMeters / 2);

    double lat4d = Math.asin(Math.sin(lat1d) * Math.cos(distanceByRadius4) +
            Math.cos(lat1d) * Math.sin(distanceByRadius4) * Math.cos(brng4));
    double lng4d = lng1d + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng4) * Math.sin(distanceByRadius4) * Math.cos(lat1d), Math.cos(distanceByRadius4) - Math.sin(lat1d) * Math.sin(lat2d));
    Point point4 = Point.at(Coordinate.fromDegrees(lat4d), Coordinate.fromDegrees(lng4d));


    double brng3 = brng4 + Math.PI; // bearing for calculating point 3
    double distanceByRadius3 = distance * 0.5 / (earthRadiusInMeters / 2);

    double lat3d = Math.asin(Math.sin(lat1d) * Math.cos(distanceByRadius3) +
            Math.cos(lat1d) * Math.sin(distanceByRadius3) * Math.cos(brng3));
    double lng3d = lng1d + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng3) * Math.sin(distanceByRadius3) * Math.cos(lat1d),
            Math.cos(distanceByRadius3) - Math.sin(lat1d) * Math.sin(lat2d));

    Point point3 = Point.at(Coordinate.fromDegrees(lat3d), Coordinate.fromDegrees(lng3d));

    System.out.println("Point3: " + point3);
    System.out.println("Point4: " + point4);

    double actualDistance = EarthCalc.gcdDistance(point3, point4); //in meters
    System.out.println("Actual distance:" + actualDistance);
}
```

And console output:

```
Point1: Point{latitude=54.2749558, longitude=18.4287748}
Point2: Point{latitude=54.4472187, longitude=18.9512795}
Current distance between points 1 and 2: 38896.62579783285
Needed distance between points 3 and 4: 77793.2515956657
Point3: Point{latitude=-0.8693568850955943, longitude=18.451667950625396}
Point4: Point{latitude=-0.8624187436224934, longitude=18.360085243458784}
Actual distance:10211.570252961072
```

Comment: note that two points do not define a rectangle iirc. But it does not really matter since you basically want to extend the distance in between the two points with each staying on the line that connected the original points and having the same distance from the center as the other, right? Have you tried doing the distance calculation yourself to get an understanding of how the geometry works?

Comment: maybe this library has everything you need (in the EarthCalc class, using "bearing" and "pointAt"
https://github.com/grumlimited/geocalc

Comment: I'm not taking into account earth's curvature (too small areas for that to matter) so for me 2 opposite corners define a rectangle :) I have tried it but have gotten some strange results so decided to ask for help.
@ThomasSallaberger thank you, going to try that lib

Answer (score 1):

For small region you can use "flat" approximation:

```
   lat3 = lat1 - 0.5*(lat2 - lat1)
   lat4 = lat1 + 1.5*(lat2 - lat1)
   and similar for longitude
```

Quick check:

```
  1 -> 54.2749558,18.4287748 (lat, lng)  
  2 -> 54.4472187,18.9512795 (lat, lng)    
  dlat = 54.4472187 - 54.2749558 = 0.172
  dlon = 18.9512795 - 18.4287748  = 0.553
  lat3 = 54.2749558 - 0.086 = 54.189
  lon3 = 18.9512795 - 0.276 = 18.675
  lat4 = 54.2749558 + 3 * 0.086 = 54.533
  lon4 = 18.9512795 + 3 * 0.276 = 19.779
```

distance calculation gives 81.11 km due to my rough rounding and sherical distortions

To account for spherical geometry, using formulas from [latlong page](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html):

I assume that "middle" is big circle arc center (half-way between corners) - it differs from coordinate average

Don't forget to transform coordinate values in radians

Get bearing from the first point:

```
 y = Math.sin(λ2-λ1) * Math.cos(φ2);
 x = Math.cos(φ1)*Math.sin(φ2) - Math.sin(φ1)*Math.cos(φ2)*Math.cos(λ2-λ1);
 brng = Math.atan2(y, x).toDegrees();
```

where   φ1,λ1 is the start point,   φ2,λ2 the end point

For one new corner - Destination point given distance and bearing from start point:

```
φ4 = Math.asin( Math.sin(φ1)*Math.cos(d/R) +
                Math.cos(φ1)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(brng) );
λ4 = λ1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(φ1),
                     Math.cos(d/R)-Math.sin(φ1)*Math.sin(φ2));
```

where R is Earth radius, d is needed distance - here `1.5 * 39 = 58.5`

and for second corner- same destination point formula with `d = 0.5*39 = 19.5` and reverse bearing `brng+Pi`

Comment: To be honest I don't want to take into account earth's curvature (small areas, not needed that kind of precision) so I guess I could simplify it by doing coordinate average to get middle point, right?

Comment: Of course. In this case `lat3 = lat1 - 0.5*(lat2 - lat1), lat4 = lat1 + 1.5*(lat2 - lat1)` and similar for longitude

Comment: I tried using both (flat approximation and takin into account earth's curavture) and unfortunetly cannot get proper results. I've added to EDIT section my code - exactly the same calculations as you proposed and console output - can you check if I didn't make any mistakes? Trying to get it right and just can't.

Comment: You made some mistakes with degrees and radians. Use degrees only for final result.